# Find timepoint when a state variable meets a condition

Tags: r, desolve

I have set up a model that looks like this

```
library(deSolve)

model <- function(t, x, parms) {
  S <- x[1]
  E <- x[2]
  I <- x[3]
  R <- x[4]
  K <- x[5]
  V <- x[6]
  #
  with(as.list(parms), {
    Q <- ifelse(t < day0 | t > day0 + duration, 0, 0.04)
    dS <- -B * S * I - Q * S
    dE <- B * S * I - r * E
    dI <- r * E - g * I
    dR <- g * I 
    dK <- r * E
    dV <- Q * S
    res <- c(dS, dE, dI, dR, dK, dV)
    list(res)
  })
}

mtime = 120

step_size = 0.2

pp <- c(day0 = 30, duration = 5, B = 0.04, r = 1/7, g = 1/7)

init = c(S = 99, E = 1, I = 0, R = 0, K = 0, V = 0)

output <- as.data.frame(lsoda(y = init, # Initial conditions for population
                              times = seq(0, mtime, step_size), # Timepoints for evaluation
                              func = model, # Function to evaluate
                              parms = pp)
                        )
```

I want to replace `Q <- ifelse(t < day0 | t > day0 + duration, 0, 0.04)` with `Q <- ifelse(t < I_change_time + day0 | t > I_change_time + day0 + duration, 0, 0.04)`, where I_change_time = first timepoint at which `I >= some value`.

My question is in `lsoda`, how do I "catch" the first time at which a state variable changed? In this case, I just want to "catch" the first time I >= some value, so that I can use it to implement a process between two timepoints.

If this is not the best way to go about it, could you please suggest an alternative solution? Thank you.

Comment: Package deSolve has several mechanisms for things like this, called "forcings", "root finding" and "events". Details can be found in the help pages `?forcings` and `?events` and in [this short tutorial](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html). Additional examples on StackOverflow can be found by browsing the `[deSolve]` topic.

Comment: Another comment: can you please simplify your model as much as possible, e.g. with only one or two state variables? Such a toy model would be easier to extend and easier to communicate.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @tpetzoldt. So far, I think what I'm getting is that I need to specify a root function for when `I >= some value` and specify the event function to catch the time. I haven't yet gotten it to work, though.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the way to go. I would recommend to start with a small toy model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking a little, I think it is easier to avoid the event function and to split the simulation in two segments:

1. The first simulation is run to the occurrence of root.
2. The final time and the final state value(s) are used as initial time and initial state for the second segment.
3. The parameter vector is changed.
4. A simulation for the second segment is run without root finding .
5. Both segments are glued together.

The following code shows a toy example with one state variable. It can of course be extended to an arbitrary number of states. As a positive side effect, it needs no "if" constructions.

```r
library("deSolve")

pharmaco <- function(t, y, p) {
  with(as.list(c(y, p)), {
    dy <- a - b * blood
    list(dy)
  })
}

parms1 <- c(
  a = 0,   # constant dosage
  b = 0.5  # decay
)

yini1  <- c(blood = 10)
times1 <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.1)

## rootfun is triggered when return value is zero
rootfun <- function(t, y, parms) {
  y["blood"] - 1
}

## solve the first segment until a root occurs
## e.g. blood concentration reaches 1.0
## important: the solver must support root finding, e.g.
## lsoda, adams or bdf, but not vode, rk4 or ode45
out1 <- ode(func = pharmaco, times = times1, y = yini1,
            parms = parms1, rootfun = rootfun, method = "lsoda")

## outcomment to inspect results
# plot(out1)
# tail(out1)

## start 2nd segment from last time step found by root function
## and set initial values to final state at this time
times2 <- seq(from = out1[nrow(out1), 1], to=10, by = 0.1)
yini2  <- out1[nrow(out1), 2]

## change parameters, e.g. set constant dosage to 1
parms2 <- c(a = 1, b = 0.5)

## run 2nd segment without root finding
out2 <- ode(func = pharmaco, times = times2, y = yini2, parms = parms2)

## glue output matrices together and assign class "deSolve"
## to make it compatible to the deSolve plot function
out <- rbind(out1, out2)
class(out) <- "deSolve"

## plot output and indicate root with dashed red line
plot(out)
abline(h = 1, col="red", lty="dashed")
abline(v = times2[1], col="red", lty="dashed")
```

[image: segmented simulation with root finding]

Comment: This worked for me. Very grateful for your help. I just want to point out that when you're binding the two results, you bind the last time point of out1 twice if you don't remove the first row of out2.